# Powershell -Rename-Item vs -Rename-Item -newname

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain to me the difference in these two statements?

```
Rename-Item $temp "\\CCMSExtract$b"

Rename-Item  $temp -NewName "\\CCMSExtract$b"
```

It seems they are redundant ways to do the same thing but is there any benefit to this `-newname` param?

Comment: Read through the differences between named and positional parameters - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference; the two lines in your example do the same thing.

If you look at the schematics for [`Rename-Item`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx):

```
Parameter Set: ByPath
Rename-Item [-Path] <String> [-NewName] <String> [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-Force]
```

you will see that the second argument is for the `-NewName` parameter.  In other words, this:

```
Rename-Item $temp -NewName "\\CCMSExtract$b"
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Rename-Item $temp "\\CCMSExtract$b"
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
Rename-Item -Path $temp -NewName "\\CCMSExtract$b"
```

Whether or not you choose to specify the parameter names explicitly depends on your personal style.

Comment: can you state your source? I appreciate your answer

Comment: The information in my answer comes from my personal knowledge as a developer. :)  But if you would like another source that says what I said, @AndyArismendi gave it in his [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: roger that! thanks for your explanation. I thought it was strange some of my sources would have that param other's wouldn't. So I thought it would be beneficial to have an explanation somewhere, as it's just an optional parameter on the sources I researched.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. The `-NewName<String>` is a positional parameter of the `Rename-Item` cmdlet, with position of 2. So using the cmdlet without explicitly specifying `-NewName` is just a shortcut syntax.

It's exactly the same as with the `-Path<String>` parameter, which specifies the item to rename and has a position of 1. You can find it documented in the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx) under the `Position?` property of the parameter.

This is how positional arguments are implemented for PowerShell cmdlets.